# How to delete a specific terms in a long array (python)?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a long array/list of numbers (from a netcdf file), and I want to a specific term which appears multiple times in the array. This is what I have:

```
lon = np.array(ncfile.variables['LONGITUDE'][:])
lon[lon>1000]=float('nan');
lat = np.array(ncfile.variables['LATITUDE'][:])
lat[lat>1000]=float('nan');
```

What I want to do is to have no values of lon/lat over 1000 (hence the 'nan'); however, I also want all 'nan's deleted from the array, as it messes up my graph.
*My question*: how do I delete all the 'nan' terms from my array? I know a similar question was asked, but it did not really answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using numpy for your arrays, you can do
    x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]

Comment: if you are using numpy for your arrays -

Comment: didn't really work, but i figured another way out. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Note: NetCDF variables are cast to numpy arrays, so there is no need to include the `np.array` call during the read in.

```
>>> lat = ncfile.variables['LATITUDE'][:]
>>> type(lat)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If you want to simply retain the portion of the lat/lon arrays that are less than 1000, you can use [numpy where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
lat_new = lat[np.where(lat < 1000.)[0]]
```